# How to convert Buffer data type to Base64 in JavaScript Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, blob

I have this code for Models:

```js
// ...
var account = {
    picture: function(account_id, callback) {
        return db.query("SELECT image_profile FROM account_info WHERE account_info_id=?", [account_id], callback);
    }
};
//...
```

And this is for Router:

```js
// ...
router.post('/picture/:id?', function(req, res, next) {
    account.picture(req.params.id, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ 'success': false });
        } else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
// ...
```

So the output JSON format like this:

```js
[
  {
    "image_profile": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
        255,
        216,
        255,
        224,
        0,// ... too long cause this is BLOB file from database
```

How can I convert that "data" on JSON to Base64?

Comment: Are you concerned about the entire JSON returned or the data property?
Since the returned object is in JSON format, you can stringify and convert to base64 encoded.
`const objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
const objJsonB64 = new Buffer(objJsonStr).toString("base64");`

Comment: Why is this question not answered? I am stuck with the same and believe i do not understand the wider issue otherwise this question would have a straight forward answer

Comment: @JamesShiztar I was change my app logic to a better one, I only store the filename in database and place the file in public folder.

Comment: A useful tip @Rowland! Your code saved me "Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(my_file)).toString('base64')"
 :D
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked:

```
let str = ""
bufferArray.forEach(function(index) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(index)
})
console.log(str)
```

In your code "data": [255,216,255,224,0,..] is bufferArray

You can use btoa(str) to Encode

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't see how your code does Base64 encoding, it will just compose a string out of the array contents.

Comment: You can use btoa(str) to Encode

Comment: so please edit your answer and add that for future reference, otherwise the question is not really answered by your response. :)